# Javascript tag not working on spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
package com.xxx.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showIndexPage(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

IndexController.java

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
      xmlns:th="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jaxb" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/styles.less}"
          href="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/styles.css"/>

    <script th:src="@{/bower_components/less/dist/less.min.js}"
            src="../../bower_components/less/dist/less.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

</div>

</div>
    <script th:href="@{/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}"
            src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

The JavaScript tag does not work on the index page. I tried many ways but I could not find a solution. rejoice if you help me

I am using Thymeleaf as a template engine

Comment: do you mean <script> tag? there is no such think as th:href in <script> tag, and also you should use th:src instead of plain src in this tag. make sure it's in this format :  <script th:src="@{//bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}">...</script>

Comment: thanks. but it does not run any javascript at all. this code does not even output. <script> console.log("ömer");</script>